# PWM values randomly interpreted invertedly

Tags: command-line, fan, fancontrol, lm-sensors

```bsh
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Linux 4.15.0
```

**Mainboard**: Gigabyte z97x Gaming 7 (kernel module: `it87`)

I am using the endpoints at `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2` to set my case fans PWM values.

Sample script to set my fan speed via script (using argv):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo 1 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm3_enable
echo 1 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm4_enable
echo 1 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm5_enable

echo $1 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm3
echo $2 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm4
echo $3 > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm5
```

This script works about 70% of times while the other 30% of times the value for pwm4 and pwm5 are interpreted in an inverted way:

```bsh
pwm(255) = 0 rpm
pwm( 0 ) = max rpm
```

**The behavior is random and varies through reboots.**

What causes PWM values being interpreted in an inverted way? Is there any way I can permanently set the way the PWM values are interpreted?

Comment: have you tried using 1 instead of 0? 1 is so small that most fan won't even run with such a low value.
I have seen pwm controlled fans that completely stop at a low pwm value and restart spinning at zero, this is probably a security feature (system crashed -> let spin the fan).

Comment: my script is being run on boot and sets all pwm values to `82`. This is the value that I found out to be slow, nearly silent but still effective. The issue is that in 30% of all cases inputting `82` results in my fans actually getting `173` (`255-82`) due to the invert bug.

Comment: OK, reading your post I assumed only zero was a problem...
What is your kernel version? it seems that this patch is related to your problem : https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9615835/, should be fixed in 4.10.2 and later

Comment: And your kernel is far after that, nothing more to say...

Comment: ;) yup. No clue what causes this and no way to fix this as it seems. Additionally it's a random issue. The best way for me to work around this is having my script find out what values the max and min boundaries are and adapt itself according to this. But I can't be the only one affected here.

Comment: Seems clearly a bug, the maintainer is  Jean Delvare <jdelvare@suse.com>, and the report should go to the linux-hwmon@vger.kernel.org mailing list.